# AHK loop High CPU Usage

Tags: loops, cpu, autohotkey

I'm running an Autohotkey script that auto capitalizes the first character of a sentence (for example in Texstudio or Chrome). The script (specifically the loop I guess) sometime causes 30–40% of CPU. Therefore, I am wondering if there is a possibility to optimize the code (maybe without using loop?) to reduce the CPU usage. Thanks in advance. Here is the code:

```
#SingleInstance force
#NoEnv
SetBatchLines -1

Loop {
if WinActive("ahk_exe texstudio.exe") or WinActive("ahk_exe chrome.exe")
Input key, I L1 M V,{Esc}{BS}{Left}{Right}{Up}{Down}{Home}{End}{PgUp}{PgDn}{Tab}
StringUpper key, key

If InStr(ErrorLevel,"EndKey")

state =

Else If InStr(".!?",key)

state = 1

Else If InStr("`t `n",key) {

If state = 1

state = 2

} Else {

If state = 2

Send {BS}{%key%}

state =

}

}

Return
```

Answer (score 1):

[SetTimer](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) consumes much less CPU because of the period.

```
#SingleInstance force
#NoEnv
#Persistent
; SetBatchLines -1

; create a group of the programs in which you want auto-capitalize
GroupAdd, auto_capitalize_group, ahk_exe texstudio.exe
GroupAdd, auto_capitalize_group, ahk_exe chrome.exe

SetTimer, auto_capitalize, 300 ; check every 300 ms
Return 

auto_capitalize: 
if !WinActive("ahk_group auto_capitalize_group")
    return  ; do nothing
; otherwise:
Input key, I L1 M V,{Esc}{BS}{Left}{Right}{Up}{Down}{Home}{End}{PgUp}{PgDn}{Tab}
StringUpper key, key
If InStr(ErrorLevel,"EndKey")
    state =
Else If InStr(".!?",key)
    state = 1
Else If InStr("`t `n",key) 
{
    If state = 1
        state = 2
} 
Else 
{
    If state = 2
        Send {BS}{%key%}
    state =
}
Return
```

Comment: Do you think if  Sleep, 300  has the same performance compare to SetTimer?

Comment: @DagicCross, the main advantage of using SetTimer is that you can add additional stuff (hotkeys, hotstsrings, functions, other timers etc.) without  the need to use other scripts that may interfere with each other.